# Data-sized horizontal bar charts in Chartist

Tags: chartist.js

I would like to display horizontal bar charts in Chartist whose height is based on the size of the data. In other words, the width can be fixed as wide as the screen, but the height, or number of bars, should vary with the size of the data.

Right now I'm using the ct-square aspect ratio, but am finding that this is often too big or too small for the data. Is there any way to free the chart size from the aspect ratio constraint?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want this: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/ExKdepG

Basically after adding a new row of data the size is adjusted so that the user can scroll through data. This is achieved with

```
let domChart = document.getElementById("bar-chart")
let currentHeight = domChart.clientHeight // Get current height
domChart.style.height = currentHeight + 100 + "px" // How much to add after adding a new row
```

Follow-up: The code above doesn't really *"adjust the height base on the size of the data"* but it helps to get an idea how to implement it. [This CodePen](https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/GRZYXzq) assigns a height based on `data.labels.length * 100`.